# What do you call a person who asks you to not do something which they do themselves?

Tags: single-word-requests

> A person tells me not to do something, while they do it all the time.

What do you call such a person? I just don't feel hypocrite suits them in this situation.

Comment: Why don't you feel "hypocrite" is suitable?

Comment: What situation?

Comment: I just felt that there might be a better word

Comment: @WS2 : For example, this person keeps on singing all the time, but when I sing, he asks me not to

Comment: A number of questions arise. Is he/she your boss? Are you both singing in tune? Would there be any particular reason to object to what you are singing - e.g. for political reasons, (Do you come from Northern Ireland, by any chance?) reasons of decency etc?

Answer (score 3):

The boss is the  only person who can tell others (his employees) not to do what he does all the time. However, there are also people (a parent, a dictator, a spouse) who act like that as part of their authoritarian character.

Those who **simply advise** others not to do what they themselves do, are really **hypocrites**. **There is no better term.**

> - [**hypocrite**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hypocrite) - noun - "a person who claims or pretends to have certain beliefs about what is right but who behaves in a way that disagrees with those beliefs"

Answer (score 0):

***irreconcilable*** /
***Double-faced*** /
***dissembler***
All of these are defined as '' A person who engages in the same behaviors he condemns others for.''
*Although the best usage for your situation is hypocrite.*
But if you think that is is contradicting you, then use ''*contradictory*''

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes 'poser' can work - 'a person who attempts to impress others by assuming or affecting a manner, degree of elegance, sentiment, etc., other than his or her true one'.